# Delayed nottification about settings changed

Tags: android, stream, handler, volumes

I have method which sets stream volumes and service which has Hadler inside for checking this changes

Method for settings streams:

```
private setStreams(Context context)
{
   AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, ringerVol, 0);
   am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, notifVol, 0);
   am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mediaVol, 0);
   am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, alarmVol, 0);
   am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, systemVol, 0);
   am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, incallVol, 0);
   am.setStreamVolume(6, btVol, 0);  

  //some other code

}
```

Serivce:

```
public class SystemSettingsChangeObserverService extends Service {

    private ContentObserver observer;
    private static Context context;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;   
        observer = new ContentObserver (new Handler()) {

            @Override
            public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                 return super.deliverSelfNotifications(); 
            }


            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                super.onChange(selfChange);
                //here I check new values of streams
            }
    }

  ...
```

Problem is, that onChange is called after "some other code" in setStreams method and not after setStreamVolume for every stream. I need this because I needto know if volumes was changed inside my application or by other way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by putting boolean key "fromApp" in SharedPreferences and check it in SystemSettingsChangeObserverService, then set the key to false